# How to disable mouseover effect on Document Library webpart

Tags: document-library, data-view-web-part, css

I'm trying to disable the mouseover effect on a document library webpart (or a generic SPLIstViewWebPart)... I tried by css, by JS but with no success at all...

Googling I find no answer...

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to set the list web part header display to none in the appearance settings. Then add a content editor web part above the list web part.

I recently did this to our company intranet page and it worked perfectly. The only customization you made need to make is the spacing between the two web parts. You should remove it through the css.